# How to implement updating(_:body:) on gestures in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, gesture

How do I correctly implement the updating(_:body:) method on a gesture in SwiftUI? Also, what is the purpose of the method? I know how `onChanged` and `onEnded` works, but I can't get my head around this one. Here's the question in code:

```
        let dragGesture = DragGesture()
            .onChanged { gestureValue in
                ...  // no problem
            }
            .onEnded { gestureValue in
                ... // no problem
            }
            .updating( ? ) { body in 
                ?  // don't understand, please help!
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

`.updating` is for reading or setting the current gesture state (which you define via `@GestureState`. This let's you read new values and then change state (maybe to `.canceled` if you drag too far, etc.)

This was a good resource in learning how to leverage it: https://nsscreencast.com/episodes/400-swiftui-gestures